# Azure datastore upload painstakingly slow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, datastore, azure-python-sdk

I'm using azure ml python sdk to upload files to azure datastore, as described in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.filedatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-data-dataset-factory-filedatasetfactory-upload-directory)

in detail:

```
workspace = Workspace(
    subs_id, resource_group, workspace_name
)
datastore = Datastore.get(
    workspace,
    datastore_name
)
Dataset.File.upload_directory(
    dataset_path_on_disk,
    (datastore, dataset_path_on_store),
    overwrite=True,
    show_progress=True,
)
```

There are some 100K files in the directory.  Each file is pretty small aprox. 0.5MB.  But uploading each of them takes more than a minute..!  So I am doing something terribly wrong here.

These files are in azure compute engine / virtual machine that is copying them from a common disk space, i.e. from `home/azureuser/cloudfiles/code/Users/`.  So it's just copying files inside the azure infra.  Both the compute engine, workspace and datastore are in the same directory/subscription/workspace and geographic location.

The datastore type is "Azure Blob Storage".

**EDIT 1**: This seems to have something to do with the huge number of files in the directory.

If I create a directory with a smaller number of files (say ~ 100), then the uploading process proceeds very fast **per file**.

It is as if after each and every file upload the `upload_directory` would be doing some weird **it, say, scanning the whole directory again, etc.?

**EDIT 2:**

If the directory to be uploaded has subdirectories then things seem to get stuck always.

If there are only files in it, then, around 50% of times, the uploading proceeds as expected: once `upload_directory` tells you that "Loading N files" then you're in the clear and the upload starts in a few seconds.  But many times it gets stuck into the "Uploading file to .." stage.

The whole `upload_directory` thing seems completely unstable / unreliable (it's microsoft, after all), so I recommend just using the local file mounts - then you can't of course send "batch jobs" to compute clusters, but I haven't anyone seen ever to use those either since it has all been made too complicated (again, microsoft).

Recommendation: just do everything "interactively" in the horrible web terminal interface.

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032295/slow-upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-python?rq=2