# Trying to use Python to upload a blob to Azure using a SAS_TOKEN

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to follow the official documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python) to upload a file to Azure.

I got the URL and SAS_TOKEN, but no login to Azure myself to check things.

I'd prefer uploading in a sync way, but the installed libraries want to await something.
The official docs seem to be just wrong, for example expecting a self parameter in classless functions.

I'm keeping my secrets in a settings.py file at the moment.

```
import asyncio
import os
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

from settings import ACCOUNT_NAME, SAS_TOKEN, AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME

from pathlib import Path
def get_blob_service_client_sas(sas_token: str = SAS_TOKEN):
    account_url = f"https://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net"
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=sas_token)
    return blob_service_client

def upload_blob_file(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name: str = AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME):
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
    data = Path('demo.png').read_bytes()
    container_client.upload_blob(name="demo.png", data=data, overwrite=True)


# Define another async function that calls the first one
async def main():
    bsc = get_blob_service_client_sas()
    print(bsc)
    await upload_blob_file(blob_service_client=bsc)

# Run the async function from a synchronous context

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code crashes with

```
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

I'd appreciate any working example to how to upload a file - even if it's curl-code, requests or httpx based.

Comment: if you are trying with sync way you  don't need to use `azure.storage.blob.aio` instead you can use `azure.storage.blob` library.

Comment: This one? (https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/) - I'll have a look.

Comment: Yep and try the same code.

Comment: @Venkatesan thanks. The examples in there do not help me, because I need a connection string (Section Create a container) - I have a SAS_TOKEN and the account name, but no account key.

Comment: You need to upload the file from local environment to azure blob storage using sas token in python right?

Comment: @Venkatesan Yes, upload (and later download). The real world file is 5 GB in size, but at the moment I'm testing with a small file.

Comment: Check the below answer.

Comment: Is the solution is solved your issue?

Comment: @Venkatesan I hope - as soon as I got the chunked 5GB uploads confirmend working, I'll mark this solved

Answer (score 1):

> Upload (and later download). The real-world file is 5 GB in size, but at the moment, I'm testing with a small file.

For uploading small files to Azure blob storage, you can use the code below.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

Account_name="venkat789"
sas_token="<sas-token>"
container_name="test"

account_url = f"https://{Account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=sas_token)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)

local_path = r"C:\users\bike.png"
blob_name = "example.png"
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

with open(local_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

**Output:**
[image]

For larger file uploads, you can use this [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032295/slow-upload-to-azure-blob-storage-with-python/75039295#75039295) by me.

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage client library for Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli&pivots=blob-storage-quickstart-scratch)